# How to run a sandboxed Tezos node in a Docker container?

Tags: node, docker, sandbox

I'm trying to run a sandboxed tezos node in a Docker container.
Since it's (to my mind) not possible using the normal tezos docker image, and I ran into issues using [granary](https://github.com/stove-labs/granary), I tried setting up a Docker container using the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y rsync git m4 build-essential patch unzip bubblewrap wget pkg-config libgmp-dev libev-dev libhidapi-dev libsodium-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev ocaml
RUN apt-get install -y libgmp-dev m4 perl
RUN wget https://github.com/ocaml/opam/releases/download/2.0.3/opam-2.0.3-x86_64-linux
RUN cp opam-2.0.3-x86_64-linux /usr/local/bin/opam
RUN chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/opam
RUN git clone https://github.com/ocaml/dune.git
WORKDIR /dune/
RUN make release
RUN make install
WORKDIR /
RUN git clone https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos.git
WORKDIR /tezos/
RUN git checkout alphanet
RUN opam init --bare --disable-sandboxing
RUN eval $(opam env)
RUN make build-deps
RUN eval $(opam env)
RUN opam update && opam upgrade -y
RUN opam config exec make
RUN export PATH=/tezos:$PATH
# RUN source ./src/bin_client/bash-completion.sh
RUN export TEZOS_CLIENT_UNSAFE_DISABLE_DISCLAIMER=Y
COPY ./start-tezos-sandbox.sh .
ENTRYPOINT ["./start-tezos-sandbox.sh"]
```

`start-tezos-sandbox.sh` looks as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

DATA_DIR='/var/run/tezos/node' /tezos/src/bin_node/tezos-sandboxed-node.sh 1 --connections 1 &
P1=$!
eval 'sleep 5 && eval '/tezos/src/bin_client/tezos-init-sandboxed-client.sh 1'' &
P2=$!
wait $P2
/tezos/src/bin_client//../../_build/default/src/bin_client/main_client.exe -base-dir /var/run/tezos/client -addr localhost -port 18731 -block genesis activate protocol Pt24m4xiPbLDhVgVfABUjirbmda3yohdN82Sp9FeuAXJ4eV9otd with fitness 1 and key activator and parameters /tezos/src/bin_client//../../scripts/protocol_parameters.json --timestamp 2019-06-21T11:20:44Z
wait $P1
```

The node starts as expected, but executing the command to activate the alpha protocol (i.e., what's aliased to `tezos-activate-alpha`) does not seem to work. Instead, the third command of `start-tezos-sandbox.sh` only yields:

```
Error:
  No matching plugin for key scheme
```

I'm not sure what's causing this error, and even whether running a sandboxed node like this is the correct approach. Is ther any other way to run a sandbox node as a Docker container? Or can this error be fixed? Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!